# SQLYog-Like MySQL GUI For Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am looking for a `MySQL` GUI for Linux (am Using Ubuntu 10.04). Don't need anything fancy -- just the ability to easily create databases / tables, be able to manually set values for table rows, run queries and see their results etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of the question [What is a good MySQL manager? on Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/34362/6969), which was asked by a SQLyog user as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use [**MySQL Workbench**](http://wb.mysql.com/) :

- it works on both Linux and Windows
- There is a free / community version
- It's a GUI, and includes, at least :

  - create / alter table using a graphical interface
  - run queries / see their results
- And there are also features that will help you create a graphical table's model -- and it'll generate the SQL to create the tables of that model.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Have fun !

Comment: In Ubuntu/Linux Mint, you just need to run:
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

Comment: Workbench is very unstable

Comment: Kervin is right,for me it keeps on crashing when connecting through SSH tunnel. Will try Sqlyog with WINE

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Navicat Lite:
[Link](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql)

- Works on Windows, Linux, OS X
- Free and payed version

Comment: Navicat Lite has been discontinued, so it's not free anymore